# Why I see another user name on my meta stackoverflow account? How to solve it?

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, user-accounts

It often happens that the user name of another colleague of mine is being displayed on my computer. It's very strange. I tried to log out multiple times and then logged in but it doesn't fix the issue.

This bug is really irritating :( Please let me know what can I do?

---

(added by casperOne, wasimbhalli is not using a sock)

From a separate account, and even when not logged in (looking at the profile page from a private browser session), the profile page for wasimbhalli shows that there are two meta accounts on the profile page:

[image: two profiles listed for wasimbhalli on profile page as viewed by others]

Both links point to the [same profile](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/178443/wasimbhalli).

Currently, there are two logins on the account (the email on the first was removed from the image below):

[image: meta logins]

Comment: That sounds weird - although stuff like this is usually on the provider's end. How are you and your colleague connected to the Internet?

Comment: We are on the same LAN. It often very often. Same was the issue few days ago :( I log out successfully, then when I try to login again, I'm not asked about my yahoo account or anything, but I'm directly logged in with my colleagues username :|

Comment: You'll need to provide more info about your LAN and how it is connected to the Internet. It could be that some router is mixing up yu guys' sessions at some point, I don't know.

Comment: What provider? OpenID/Facebook etc?

Comment: I'm using yahoo as a log in ID, but it's not asking for log in. It automatically logs me in :s

Comment: What is your colleague using?

Comment: It might be possible that the credentials of one of you might be cached in your lan/proxy so it confuses the site when you log on.  I remember seeing people report behavior like this a number of times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was a hiccup in our network event aggregation.  Those responsible have been properly chastised.

Comment: Go easy on the hamsters. We don't want ASPCA knocking on the door again.